# How to call matlab function from c#

Tags: c#, matlab

I'm building a sample function with Matlab. The function is this:

```
function output = freqDomainHRV(ibi,VLF,LF,HF,AR_order,window, ...
    noverlap,nfft,fs,methods,flagPlot)
   //code

end
```

now, to call this function, I can use this code:

```
output = freqDomainHRV(sampledata,[0 .16],[.16 .6],[.6 3], ...
%                       16,256,128,512,10,{'welch','ar','lomb'},1);
```

Now, I want to call this function from C# program, so I'm building a dll from matlab, I have imported it in my visual studio project, then I'm write this code:

```
private void calculateFreqDomainHRV()
        {
            //costruisco l'array contenente i valori dell ECG
            MWNumericArray res = new MWNumericArray(new double[] { 0.789, 0.828, 0.844, 0.820 });
            MWNumericArray vlf = new MWNumericArray(new double[] { 0, 0.04 });
            MWNumericArray lf = new MWNumericArray(new double[] { 0.04, 0.15 });
            MWNumericArray hf = new MWNumericArray(new double[] { 0.15, 0.40 });
            MWCellArray method = new MWCellArray(3);
            method[1] = new MWCharArray("welch");
            method[2] = new MWCharArray("ar");
            method[3] = new MWCharArray("lomb");
            var arOptionOrder = 16;
            var winWith = 128;
            var winOverlap = 64;
            var pointPSD = 1024;
            var interpolationRate = 2;
            /*freqDomainHRV(sampledata,[0 .16],[.16 .6],[.6 3], ...
% 16, 256, 128, 512, 10);*/
            var output = matlab.freqDomainHRV(res, vlf, lf,hf, arOptionOrder, winWith, winOverlap, pointPSD, interpolationRate, method,1);
}
```

but if I try to call this method, I have this error message:

```
. MWMCR::EvaluateFunction error ... 
Interpolation requires at least two sample points in each dimension.
Error in => freqDomainHRV.m at line 97.

... Matlab M-code Stack Trace ...
    at
file D:\MATLAB\R2018a\mcr\toolbox\matlab\polyfun\interp1.p, name interp1, line 0.
    at
file C:\Users\michele.castriotta\AppData\Local\Temp\mik\mcrCache9.4\Matlab2\MatlabECG\freqDomainHRV.m, name calcWelch, line 145.
    at
file C:\Users\michele.castriotta\AppData\Local\Temp\mik\mcrCache9.4\Matlab2\MatlabECG\freqDomainHRV.m, name freqDomainHRV, line 97.
```

Comment: What does `sampledata` look like in your MATLAB code?

Comment: The input arguments in the MATLAB code and in the C# code are not the same. Please try first with exactly the same values. That will convince us that the problem is not inside your M-file, which you are not disclosing.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by https://github.com/jramshur/HRVAS/blob/master/freqDomainHRV.m
first option should be a 2Darray (ibi = 2Dim array of time (s) and inter-beat interval (s)).

However you prescribe a 1D array as Input (variable `res`), hence the error I believe.

As @KevinK. and  @CrisLuengo suggested try to test your function without varying any parameters from the Matlab test case.